# Spray rest with webapp serving

Tags: scala, spray

Hi I have code in spray application like:

```
def receive: Actor.Receive = {
    case _: Http.Connected => sender ! Http.Register(self)

    case HttpRequest(POST, Uri.Path("/stats"), _, _, _) =>
```

and I would like to add code like:

```
 path("") {
      getFromResource("webapp/index.html")
    } ~ getFromResourceDirectory("webapp")
```

but matching to this pattern match, any one know how to deal with it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change the receive to something like this

```
def receive = runRoute(webRoute)
```

Have an service something like this

```
trait WebService extends HttpService {

    val webRoute = path("") {
               getFromResource("webapp/index.html")
               } ~ getFromResourceDirectory("webapp")
           // check with this code 

}
```

Also extend this trait to you "extened actor" which has the def recive method in it.

Comment: but isnt there a wary to insert this stuff into this pattern match ? only making another traits ? ;x smth like:  case HttpRequest(GET, Uri.Path(""), _, _, _) =>
      val test = getFromResource("webapp/index.html") ~ getFromResourceDirectory("webapp")
      sender ! HttpEntity(`text/html`, test) ( but this doesnt work ;x )

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your comment. May be there are other ways, I haven't looked much but breaking this into trait is pretty nice as you can have very modular routes and part of application.